# Update file in Windows Azure CDN

Tags: cdn, azure-storage

I have blob storage and CDN endpoint, that store my static content.
Now I want to update app.js file, because it was modified, but when I write this file to blob, CDN still gives me old app.js file. How can I update my app.js file? Or I have to wait until my cache is not going to end?

Comment: I really need the answer to this question also.  I've tried messing with the cache-control headers, but not sure what to do with them. I can upload a file with a new name, and its shows up immediately, but modifications to the existing file are still not showing up after 72 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can't update the cache object before its expiration.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg680303.aspx:

> If you no longer wish to cache an object in the Azure Content Delivery Network (CDN), you can take one of the following steps:
>
> - For a Azure blob, you can delete the blob from the public container.
> - You can make the container private instead of public. See Restrict Access to Containers and Blobs for more information.
> - You can disable or delete the CDN endpoint using the Azure Management Portal.
> - You can modify your hosted service to no longer respond to requests for the object.
>
> An object already cached in the CDN will remain cached until the time-to-live period for the object expires. When the time-to-live period expires, the CDN will check to see whether the CDN endpoint is still valid and the object still anonymously accessible. If it is not, then the object will no longer be cached.
>
> No explicit "purge" tool is currently available for the Azure CDN.

Other workarounds include using either fake query strings or new file names, if possible. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8773202/908336

Answer (score 2):

Question was asked quite long ago. I just wanted to update on method that proved useful for me. Its recommended by Microsoft. Essentially you need to set up cache-control headers in your Blob Storage. You can set cache control header with value "public, max-age=3600". This will cache your file for about 1 hour.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-manage-expiration-of-blob-content/

Answer (score 1):

The CDN is simple. When a request comes in, it fetches the content from the origin (in this case, blob storage), and then caches it for some time based on the `Cache-Control` header. It will keep delivering the same content until the cache expires.

There's no way to tell the CDN to expire something early.

Others may jump in with more helpful advice about how to deal with this (like query string parameters), but I just wanted to give a straightforward explanation of how the CDN's caching works.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Do you know what the behavior is if the Cache-Control header is blank on that particular blob?

Comment: This info may be out of date, but at one point the heuristic was that the CDN would cache the content for a duration of (now - las modified), up to a maximum of, if I recall correctly, 72 hours. So if the last-modified header indicates that the content is three hours old, the CDN will cache it for the next three hours before checking again. But note that this could certainly have changed, and it's not a very good idea to rely on the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this right this now is to contact Azure Support and they will in turn open a support ticket with Verizon EdgeCast to remove the file from the CDN and it will update at that point. This whole process takes about 8 hours on the basic Azure support plan. This isn't a good solution and I really hope they update this to where we can programmatically purge something from the CDN. This seems like a basic feature they are lacking. Your best bet I think right now is to enable querystring status and then update that querystring when you update. We do this for js files like so /js/custommix.js?version=1. Then we append a new version from our config when we need to update those.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/best-practices-for-the-windows-azure-content-delivery-network/

**How can I purge or invalidate content in the Windows Azure CDN?**

As of 1.4, no purge function is available. This feature is under development. The best freshness control is to set good cache expiration headers as described in this document and the Windows Azure CDN documentation on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can purge the content from Azure new Management portal.

Answer (score -1):

It appears the default expiration time is 7 days.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg680306.aspx

> Blobs that benefit the most from Azure CDN caching are those that are
> accessed frequently during their time-to-live (TTL) period. A blob
> stays in the cache for the TTL period and then is refreshed by the
> blob service after that time is elapsed. Then the process repeats.
>
> You have two options for controlling the TTL:
>
> 1. Do not set cache values thus using the default TTL of 7 days.
> 2. Explicitly set the x-ms-blob-cache-control property on a Put Blob, Put
>    Block List, or Set Blob Properties request, or use the Azure Managed
>    Library to set the BlobProperties.CacheControl property. Setting this
>    property sets the value of the Cache-Control header for the blob. The
>    value of the header or property should specify the appropriate value
>    in seconds. For example, to set the maximum caching period to one
>    year, you can specify the request header as x-ms-blob-cache-control:
>    public, max-age=31556926. For details on setting caching headers, see
>    the HTTP/1.1 specification.